# refreshing form in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

Is there any function to refresh form in cakephp.

Comment: what you could do is store the form html in a jquery object and on some button click or other event, restore the html of the form back to what it originally was in the object you saved on page load. I've used this technique a few times but depending on the jQuery version you'll need to use `live` or `on`. I think `on` is now deprecated as of 1.9 so not sure what you do in that scenario...

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP being PHP, the function would be to refresh the page. Perhaps you are looking for an Ajax or Javascript solution that changes parts of the form according to values entered elsewhere?

Comment: can you help me how to refresh cakephp form using ajax or javascript

Comment: You don't refresh CakePHP, you would use javascript to rewrite parts of the form and perhaps AJAX to retrieve the information from the database. If you don't know how to use javascript, there are plenty of tutorials online.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery `window.reload()`. :)

Comment: Can you please clarify your questions? So that we can help you with your current problem. :)